# Accessing a resource bundle file in java which placed in project's some other folder other than a package

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I want to access a properties file placed in a folder,which is at the project level .Means the .properties file will not be part of any package.
The structure would be like below.

```
Project 
      Src
        package1
         |
         ------file1.java
        package2
          |
          -----file2.java
SimpleFolder
   |       
    -----myfile.properties
```

now from file1.java,I want to access the myfile.properties file values.

Please help me out if any one can

Comment: Already answered : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251289/how-to-read-a-properties-file-in-java-from-outside-the-class-folder
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775303/read-properties-file-outside-jar-file

Comment: Hi Sayyid thanks for your reply.but I want to access the values using resource bundle and locale objects only.Any solution