# Loading .properties file from another location

Tags: java

I'm using Resource bundle and I want to load .properties file into my Java file at run time from different directory. Is it possible ? Will it work after creating executable JAR also ?

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("G:\myProject\test.properties");
        Enumeration<String> enumKeys = bundle.getKeys();
        while(enumKeys.hasMoreElements()){
            System.out.println(enumKeys.nextElement());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a properties file in java from outside the Class folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251289/how-to-read-a-properties-file-in-java-from-outside-the-class-folder)

Comment: Err...do you even need to use a resource bundle or could you just use the Properties class? In the later case, just load it from a FileInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Use a URL class loader to add files from a directory to the classpath:

```
File file = new File("G:\myProject");
URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test", Locale.getDefault(), loader);

Enumeration<String> enumKeys = bundle.getKeys();
while(enumKeys.hasMoreElements()){
    System.out.println(enumKeys.nextElement());
}
```